# Software to measure stress on video card

Tags: windows-7, benchmarking

I have been searching for software that can measure stress on video cards. I have an integrated Intel(R) HD Graphics card and I would like to test it.

Is there any software that can accomplish this?
I am running Windows 7, portable and free software is preferred.
**Update:** What I am trying to do is:
I want to find out the stress on my video card with and without [Windows Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero)(and other visuaL effects) running.

Comment: https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/

Comment: Do you actually want to measure **performance** (FPS, quality of rendering)? Or do you really want to measure **stress** (excessive temperatures, board bending, faulty electrical power, etc)?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The second one.

Comment: So, that means the current answer is off-topic, if I understand correctly? You might want to make your requirements extra-clear to prevent more off-topic answers. At least, please state the metrics (and for each the units) that you want the software to measure. That way you will get greater answers :-) By the way, welcome to SR!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please specify the measurement units you want, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Actually, I do not know what to measure. Would you tell me what to measure?

Comment: What is your final goal? Do you want to know how powerful your card is? Do you want to know how much risk there is that your card will become unusable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26432/discussion-between-rogue-and-nicolas-raoul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals to fulfil my requirement.
[image: Process Explorer]
I gives real-time GPU usage with graphs, and I hope it is the tool that I was serching.
[image: Info]
To get to the GPU information, press **View**, then **System Information** will get a new window, in which, switch to the **GPU** tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the cinebench OpenGL test. It stress tests your graphics card by running a pretty complex 3D scene. The result will be given in how fast the scene ran in FPS. Cinebench also has a CPU test

Comment: Could you add a link and a screenshot? By the comments under the question it appears the OP looks for increase in temperature rather then throughput in FPS. Does the tool you mention cover that? Have a nice day.