# GPU stress test tool

Tags: video, software-testing, hardware, benchmarking, gpu

What is the most efficient tool for stress-testing the **onboard** video-adapter? I have Intel HD 530, if that matters.

The most reasonable tool I've found for now is Geek3d's [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/). It does quite good, **however**! 
It doesn't support multi-GPU systems, and I have discrete video too. Which makes it useless, because it tests only my Nvidia card and [my problems](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/643576/windows-10-completely-freezes-no-bsod/) probably are connected with onboard adapter.

P.S. Yes, I read [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21573/software-to-measure-stress-on-video-card), but it doesn't address my problem fully. It mostly focuses on **measuremen**t GPU load, and doesn't touch the point **how to achieve** this load.